# Arc length of a point on ellipse from the vertex

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, conic-sections, arc-length

How is the arc length of an ellipse (measured from the vertex) defined by $x = a \cos (\theta)$, $y = b \sin(\theta)$ given by $s(\psi) = a Elliptic\left(\psi,\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}\right) $. Please see my attempt below
\begin{align*}
s(\psi) &~=~\int_{0}^{\psi} \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{d\theta}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{dy}{d\theta}\right)^2} d\theta
\\
&~=~ \int_{0}^{\psi} \sqrt{ a^2 \sin^2(\theta)+b^2\cos^2(\theta)} d\theta
\\
&~=~ \int_{0}^{\psi} \sqrt{ a^2 (1-\cos^2(\theta))+b^2\cos^2(\theta)} d\theta
\\
&~=~ \int_{0}^{\psi} \sqrt{ a^2+(b^2-a^2)\cos^2(\theta)} d\theta
\\
&~=~ a \int_{0}^{\psi} \sqrt{ 1-\left(1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)\cos^2(\theta)} d\theta,
\end{align*}
which is not equal to 
\begin{align*}
s(\psi) &~=~ a Elliptic\left(\psi,\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}\right) 
\\
&~=~a  \int_{0}^{\psi} \sqrt{ 1-\left(1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)\sin^2(\theta)}. 
\end{align*}

Comment: You are attempting to do what, exactly? The integral representation for the length is correct, and it is an elliptic integral (of the second kind).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Please see the last three lines added to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For clockwise sense:

  \begin{align}
     (x,y) &= (a\sin \theta,b\cos \theta) \\
     s(\theta) &= aE(\theta, \varepsilon) \\
     \varepsilon &= \sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}
   \end{align}
- For anti-clockwise sense:

  \begin{align}
     (x,y) &= (a\cos \theta,b\sin \theta) \\
     s(\theta) &= bE\left( \theta, \frac{ia\varepsilon}{b} \right) \\
     &= aE\left( \frac{\pi}{2}-\theta, \varepsilon \right) \\
     \frac{ia\varepsilon}{b} &= \sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}}
   \end{align}
- Parametrized with Jacobi elliptic functions:

  \begin{align}
     (x,y) &= (a\operatorname{sn} (u,\varepsilon),
               b\operatorname{cn} (u,\varepsilon)) \\
     s(u) &= aE( \operatorname{am} ( u,\varepsilon ), \varepsilon ) \\
   \end{align}

> See also the arclength formula in polar coordinates [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800694/arc-length-of-ellipse-in-polar-coordinates/2800844#2800844).

Comment: I think for clockwise sense $(x,y)=\left(a\cos(t),-b\sin(t)\right)$. How do you define the clockwise sense?

Comment: The start point for my definition is $(0,b)$ while your start point is $(a,0)$ that is a phase shift of $90^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to exchange $a$ and $b$, and use $\cos^2=1-\sin^2$. Then the two expressions agree. So it's just a question of how you define your ellipse.

Alternatively, you can look on the elliptic integral as measuring the arc length anticlockwise from the point $(0,b)$.

Comment: For my ellipse definition $a =$ semi-major axis, and the arc length is measured anti-clockwise from the point $(a,0)$. I can't see how the two expressions would agree.