# How to parametrize eliptic curve?

Tags: conic-sections, curves, python

```
def curve(t, radiusX, radiusY):
    x = sin(t*pi/2) * radiusX
    y = cos(t*pi/2) * radiusY
    return (x,y)
```

Following Python pseudo-code will draw a part 1/4 of an ellipse.
However, I am looking to stop drawing at given Y, as I don't need full 1/4 of this ellipse.

Can this function be parametrized such that it will stop drawing at given Y, without affecting the curve < Y?

An alternative approach is to draw using the current function and then cut the resulting object to given max height from the bottom, which I am trying to simplify.

I think the *direction* of the solution is to keep y at constant *step* using `y = t * radiusY` while `x` should be a transformed formula that will tell us what's the proper `x` given our `y`?

Comment: The term "elliptic curve" has a different meaning in Mathematics. What you want is an "arc of an ellipse".

Comment: From the given Y you can compute the corresponding value of t and stop there.

Comment: it would be against the whole idea of parametrization, to be honest

Comment: Just solve for $t$ in $Y = \cos(t\cdot \pi/2)\cdot \text{radiusY}$

Comment: is `y = t * height` `x = radiusX/radiusY*sqrt(radiusY*radiusY-y*y)` a proper formula? it seems to bug out at lower height (at least)

Comment: ok, I believe the above formula is correct, but I had unrealistic combination of radiusX/radiusY/height. I am working on a CAD model right now, and they will get auto-calculated as I progress the model...

Comment: I think height can also be represented in angle form, which will be easier

Comment: For further interests, please refer to a post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2921627/arc-length-of-a-point-on-ellipse-from-the-vertex/2922306#2922306).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
def curve(phi, radiusX, radiusY):
    r = 1/sqrt( sin(phi)**2/radiusX**2 + cos(phi)**2/radiusY**2)
    x = sin(phi) * r
    y = cos(phi) * r
    return (x,y)
```

and now `phi` represents the polar angle of the ellipse, with `0` at the 12 o'clock positon and moving clockwise. So if you only want 1/4 of an ellipse use `phi  = 0..pi/2`

This follows the polar coordinate definition for a centered, axis-aligned ellipse

$$r(\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\sin^{2}\theta}{a^{2}}+\frac{\cos^{2}\theta}{b^{2}}}}$$

and then $x = r \sin \theta$ and $y = r \cos \theta$.

Comment: thank you, I went with `y = t * height` `x = radiusX/radiusY*sqrt(radiusY*radiusY-y*y)` which turned out very well

Comment: This won't work if the ellipse extends to the negative _x_ areas.